Different amount of requests to server. Why?
All commands of gspread send requests?
Here error 429 doesnt raise
gc = gs.service_account(filename="service_files/creds.json")
wks = gc.open_by_key("url have 35 list")
article = []
price = []
batch_data = wks.worksheets()
for data in batch_data:
    article.extend(data.col_values(3))
    price.extend(data.col_values(4))
print(article)

But Here error raises
gc = gs.service_account(filename="service_files/creds.json")
article = []
price = []
for i in range(1,35):
    wks = gc.open_by_key("url have 35 list").get_worksheet(i)
    article.extend(wks.col_values(3))
    price.extend(wks.col_values(4))
print(article)

How does this work?
In the first example, we send request once, right?
In the second example we send request 35 times, 35 request per user less than 60 request per user, yeah?
What if col_values send request, why first example work?

Calls to server:

col_values sends request to server each time as seen in code.

Also, open_by_key uses get_sheet_metadata(), which makes another call.

In addition, get_worksheet also seems to call get_sheet_metadata. This isn't cached in the first call AFAICS. The reasoning provided by the contributor is here.


So, total calls is almost double in the second code:



Function
First code
Second code




col_values(3)
35
35


col_values(4)
35
35


open_by_key()
1
35


worksheets()
1
0


get_worksheet()
0
35


Total
72
140



As written in the docs, the only relevant calls that are batched seems to get(), get_all_values()  and batch_get():
https://docs.gspread.org/en/v6.1.3/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-row-or-a-column

I understand. Well, if we open_by_key use one time, we can reduce amount of request by 35 times in second example, but why second example crush and first dont? How much request actually may be?

@Teramisu Did you run second after the first within 1 minute? The quota is 60/min/user/project

Yes, I ran the last time yesterday. I'm running now and error occur anyway

Thanks for the answer, i understand and remake code. The first example also dont work

@Teramisu Are you using the same creds.json in another live project -using it elsewhere?

No, I run code if I need. But ~6 requests send automatically at 00:00

does it make sense? The first and the second example send more 60 requests, so code doesnt work
